# Centering a div using jQuery - on page load div is loaded offset to the right rails 5 , semantic-ui

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, html, css, semantic-ui

So I am newish to jQuery, I am attempting to vertically and horizontally to the page, however on the initial page load the login-form is loading offset a bit to the right. if i am in the browser and drag the screen wider or smaller the div centres its self on the screen, however on a mobile device, where you can not expand the screen it wont recenter its self.

her is the code i am using for the jQuery:

```
$(window).resize(function(){

  $('.login-form').css({
    position:'absolute',
    left: ($(window).width() - $('.login-form').outerWidth())/2,
    top: ($(window).height() - $('.login-form').outerHeight())/2
  });

});
```

and then in the view I have:

```
<script>
  $(window).resize();
</script>
```

and my login form css:

```
  /* Login Screen */
  .login-form{
    height: auto;
    width: 80%;
  }
```

and for brevity here is my login page form:

```
<div class="ui stacked segment login-form">

  <section class="login-header animated slideInUp">
    <center>
      <%= render partial: 'shared/pv_login' %>
    </center>
  </section>

  <section>
    <div class="ui form">
      <%= simple_form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: session_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
      <center>
        <div class="eleven wide field">
          <div class="ui left icon input">
            <i class="user icon"></i>
            <input type="email" name="user[email]" placeholder="E-mail address">
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="eleven wide field">
          <div class="ui left icon input">
            <i class="unlock icon"></i>
            <input type="text" name="user[password]" placeholder="Password">
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="inline field">
          <div class="ui checkbox">
            <input name="user[remember_me]" type="hidden" value="false" />
            <input type="checkbox" id="remember_me" name="user[remember_me]" value="true" />
            <label>Remember me</label>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="button-group">
          <div class="ui buttons">
            <%= f.submit "Sign In", :class => 'ui positive button', :id => 'sign-in-button' %>
          </div>
        </div>
      </center>
      <% end %>
    </div>
  </section>

</div>
```

Thanks in advance for your assistance! please let me know if you require anything further!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the width and height of the login-form then this can be done easily with css like so:

```
.login-form {
  top:50%;
  margin-top:-200px; //this value should be half of the height of login-form
  left:50%;
  margin-left:-150px; // this value should be half of the width of login-form
}
```